# Enqueue CSS on custom posts' backend area

Tags: posts, wp-admin, wp-enqueue-style

I'd like to insert some CSS on a specific post type's backend area. So not globally. I've found lots of ways to insert it everywhere, but can't figure out how you'd target posts only. Any ideas?

Comment: You could wrap it in a `if` condition, [is_single()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) or [is_singular()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/), adding your enqueued code into the question would help understand how you are adding your style.

Comment: What part of the backend do you want to style? And are you using the Classic Editor or the Block Editor?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast How would that look?

Comment: @JacobPeattie The "edit post" part. I'd like this to work no matter which I choose, but Classic at the moment.

Comment: @Fluxian So the actual content inside the Visual editor? I ask because it's a different process to style that than the editor itself.

Comment: No not the content, the surrounding UI.

Comment: @Fluxian the solution is super super specific to wether you use the classic editor or the block editor, there is no one size fits all solution, pick one, you can always ask a follow up question for the other

Comment: @TomJNowell I fail to see how enqueuing CSS on edit.php for a custom post type is hyper-specific to your choice of editor. But if you know how to do it feel free to provide the solution for the classic editor.

Comment: because how you do it right for the block editor and how you do it right for the classic editor are different. They both have different answers because they are both built in totally different ways with different paradigms, it's even likely that the CSS itself will need to be different for each editor because of where the CSS needs to be applied and the HTML classes involved. In the meantime your question does not mention which editor you are using, you must specify which editor you are asking about, use the `Edit` link to adjust your question so that users do not need to go through comments

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you intend to style the content of the post, not the UI of the editor, it would be helpful if you can clarify this explicitly to avoid misunderstandings when you edit the question (the 2 answers you got already have misunderstood your question, I'd suggest editing it to make it clearer to other people as not everyone appears to have understood)

Comment: @TomJNowell Don't sweat it. I figured it out myself. Obviously whichever editor is chosen has zero impact on the solution.

Comment: @Fluxian if you figured it out yourself then you should answer your own question. If you don't the site will keep bumping it to the top trying to attract new people to get you an answer

Comment: @TomJNowell You assume wrong. Your assumption has already been addressed earlier.

Comment: @Fluxian please edit your question to avoid assumptions and misunderstandings, and if you have a solution post it below so that other users can benefit

Comment: If you have found the solution, you should post it below as an answer

Answer (score -4):

Just use the Page-ID class e.g. 123 and use plugin like Custom CSS. There you do:

```
.page-id-123 { 

font-size: 100px; }
```

You may need to add a class as well if you want to style a certain object.

Comment: What page-id is shared across all posts of a certain type in the wp-admin area?

Comment: this works for the frontend, it does not work for the backend, the question is for WP Admin